# Show hide in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want a show hide function for my ionic app:

Below is what I have done so far, in xyz.html file:

```
<ion-item>    
<p class="font_c_2 gra_reg" (click)="onPtagClick(part.reg_id)"  *ngIf="!PtagClicked">
          {{part.fsp_partner_location}}
</p>
<p class="font_c_2 gra_reg" *ngIf="PtagClicked" (click)="onPtagClick1(part.reg_id)"  style="white-space:normal;">
          {{part.fsp_partner_location}}
</p>
</ion-item>
```

my xyz.ts file

```
export class xyzpage{
public PtagClicked: boolean = false;

public onPtagClick(id) {         
    {        
     this.PtagClicked = !this.PtagClicked;          
    }           
  }
 public onPtagClick1(id) {
   {            
    this.PtagClicked = false;   

    }           
  }
}
```

My problem is, I have dynamic numbers of  created on this page, and if I click on 1 item, it show/hide all item's data and not the one I clicked for.

I guess the problem will be solved if I can create dynamic values for ngIf, but I tried and not able to as I am new to ionic.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have latest IONIC installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to addClass, setStyle, or whatever you want, passing the element reference to your click event handler

Here a [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8nt3vb)

## HTML

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h3 #text>{{item}}</h3>
  <button ion-button item-right (click)="onShow(text)">Show</button>
  <button ion-button color="danger" item-right (click)="onHide(text)">Hide</button>
</ion-item>
```

## TS

```
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

public items: string[] = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6",
    "Item 7",
    "Item 8",
    "Item 9",
    "Item 10",   
];

  public PtagClicked: boolean = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private render: Renderer2) { }

  public onShow(controlToShow) {
    this.render.setStyle(controlToShow, 'visibility', 'visible');
  }
  public onHide(controlToHide) {
    this.render.setStyle(controlToHide, 'visibility', 'hidden');
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. this is for "let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" ?

Comment: ngFor will loop whatever array you pass... hardcoded like mine, or from a model. It dosn't matter. Check [this to learn more](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_for_directive.html) .

Comment: It is not about a unique ID. You pass the reference to the event handler. the whole HTML node will be passed. Which is unique in its specific context when ngFor is doing its job.

Comment: you set the reference #text and then pass is as a variable onShow(text). If you console.log() the parameter in the onShow() event handler you will see what is passed

Comment: I've just edited the answer, using a model. Check if you understand it better now

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.

Comment: Can you also help here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083907/switch-between-2-values-in-a-class

Comment: done, the other answers you have in the other thread are not bad as well