# Switch between 2 values in a class

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to switch between 2 values in a class.

Something like this,

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let part of partner" class="border_bottom bdr_radius">
<p class="font_c_2 gra_reg" #short (click)="onShowHide(short)" [ngStyle]="{'white-space': whiteSpace}">
  {{part.fsp_partner_location}} 
</p>
</ion-item>

public onShowHide(controlToShow) {

this.render.setStyle(controlToShow, white-space=='normal' ? 'nowrap' : 'normal');

}
```

Above code is throwing an error: "white is not defined"

I know my format is not correct, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is `white-space` inside of the component ts file?

Comment: white-space is actually a css class property which i want to change on click

Comment: white-space=='normal' ? 'nowrap' : 'normal' as second argument of setstyle makes no sense, you should check the docs for the rendered implementation that you are using

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now when I know your code this is what I will do :

HTML part:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let part of partner; let i=index" class="border_bottom bdr_radius"> 
<p class="font_c_2 gra_reg" #short (click)="onShowHide(i)" [ngClass]="{'long': selected === i, 'short': selected != i}"> 
{{part.fsp_partner_location}} 
</p> 
</ion-item>
```

css part:

```
.long {
    white-space: normal;
}
.short{
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

your ts file:

```
selected = 0;

onShowHide(index: number) {
   this.selected = index;
}
```

When you click on item it will set `normal` for it and others will `have` nowrap

Comment: throwing error:  white is not defined

Comment: How did you intend to change white space? By clicking on something or by something else?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Please read my edited answer

Comment: After your edit, I changed my code, please read it now.

Comment: my 2 cents that `-` cannot be part of identifiers in typescript.

Comment: white-space is CSS style, not typescript identifier

Comment: It worked, but it is again changing class of all the items and not the one I have clicked on.

Comment: You have more then one item? Then set [ngStyle] on all of them and you must have one variable like that whiteSpace for each one, like whiteSpace2, whiteSpace3  etc. And you must have more on click events.

Comment: I edited my answer for more then one item.

Comment: It's like this,  <ion-item *ngFor="let part of partner" class="border_bottom bdr_radius">
<p class="font_c_2 gra_reg" #short (click)="onShowHide(short)" [ngStyle]="{'white-space': whiteSpace}">
  {{part.fsp_partner_location}} 
</p>
</ion-item>

Comment: repeating the loop will be dynamic and not n any fixed number

Comment: You nedd to add index in ngFor, and then change style of items by index value

Comment: I have changed my code based on what you wrote. Please check does this help you

Comment: @BalázsÉdes OP just doesnt know what he is doing, and that the error is caused because typescript is trying to find a locale variable called white-space.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
this.render.setStyle(controlToShow, white-space=='normal' ? 'nowrap' : 'normal');
```

Comment: throwing error: white is not defined

Answer (score -2):

To do it on click event, just set and event handler and pass the control. then chech which is your current class and apply the logic you want to apply a new one

[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-aretot)

## HTML

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h3 #text>{{item}}</h3>
    <button ion-button item-right color="light" (click)="onSwitch(text)">Switch Primary / Danger</button>
    <button ion-button item-right (click)="onPrimary(text)">Set Primary</button>
    <button ion-button color="danger" item-right (click)="onDanger(text)">Set Danger</button>
  </ion-item>
```

## TS

```
  public items: string[] = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5",
    "Item 6",
    "Item 7",
    "Item 8",
    "Item 9",
    "Item 10",
  ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private render: Renderer2) { }

  public onSwitch(control) {
    if(control.classList.contains('primary')){
      this.render.removeClass(control, 'primary');
      this.render.addClass(control, 'danger');
    }
    else{
      this.render.removeClass(control, 'danger');
      this.render.addClass(control, 'primary');
    }

  }
  public onPrimary(control) {
    this.render.addClass(control, 'primary');
  }
  public onDanger(control) {
    this.render.addClass(control, 'danger');
  }
```

Otherwise, use the one of the other answers

Comment: It seems to be a CSS rule rather than a boolean variable.

Comment: fixed... I just guessed it was a variable because of the conversation we had here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082846/show-hide-in-ionic-framework/49083264?noredirect=1#comment85173045_49083264

Comment: it is again changing class of all items and not the one i clicked

Comment: This is because you didn't mention anything about clicking in your question at the begining. But no problem my friend. I have edited my answer so you can apply the logic you want for each specific control avoiding setting variables variable